# ¿Cómo extraer el texto de un parámetro de una línea de un log?

Tags: python

¿Alguien sabe cómo es posible extraer el texto que se encuentre luego de varios espacios en blanco en una línea de log?

Busco extraer el elemento que se encuentra posterior a la hora, en la cuarta posición. Este elemento, hay veces que lo recibo en formato IP (`123.123.123.123`) y otras veces en formato de texto (`abc`) ya que llega el nombre del hostname.

Ejemplos de la entrada y la salida esperada:

```
 Input: <2>Mar 13 21:34:09 12.11.18.67 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes,
 Output: 12.11.18.67

 Input: <2>Mar 13 21:34:09 local.prueba 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes,
 Output: local.prueba
```

Mi intento fue capturar la IP usando regex:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Pero eso no me vale para los casos que la IP llegue con el nombre del host.

Comment: ¿Dónde están los "*varios espacios en blanco*"? Lo único que veo es un String del que se quiere obtener la 4ta palabra. Basta con `texto.split(" ")[3]` ... No veo la necesidad de usar una expresión regular.

Comment: Podrías cortar el String cada vez que encuentres un espacio vacío, y sí siempre viene en dicho formato, sería el 4to elemento siempre.

Comment: Lo primero que pense fue en regex, pero probare con lo que me comentais. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días, lo que debes hacer es cortar el String, con la función `split()` que le puedes aplicar al String.

La función split(), así sin ningún argumento, cortará cada vez que encuentre un espacio.

Yo hice una corrida con tus textos en la página [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python), y como se puede ver la en imagen, lo que se nos devuelve es un arreglo con strings, en donde en los dos casos, el cuarto elemento es el dominio o la ip, según corresponda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo [documentación](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) (En Inglés) en donde va incluido este método.

Por tanto, la siguiente línea de código bastaría para poder obtener la información que deseas.

```
'<2>Mar 13 21:34:09 12.11.18.67 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes,'.split()[3]

'<2>Mar 13 21:34:09 local.prueba 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes,'.split()[3]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es genial tu respuesta, muy currada! muchas gracias por la ayuda de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Nota: Esta respuesta es para la pregunta original "¿Cómo con regex extraer el texto luego de ciertos espacios en blanco de un parámetro de una línea de un log?" que ha sido manipulada para adaptarse a una respuesta diferente.

En Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile('^Input:\s+[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s([^\s]+).*$')
m=p.match("Input: <2>Mar 13 21:34:09 12.11.18.67 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes,")
print m.group(1)
m=p.match("Input: <2>Mar 13 21:34:09 local.prueba 1,2017/08/08 21:34:09,62701006152,lunes")
print m.group(1)
```

Esto lo puedes probar en Notepad++ y despues traducirlo a regex de Java o al lenguaje que estés usando. `^Input:\s+[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s([^\s]+).*$`

La expresión en paréntesis se puede extraer o usar como sustituto en la linea original.

[image: Dialogo en Notepad++]

Comment: Porqué el "-1" ???

Comment: Xav: También puedes escribir un programa que lea cada linea de un archivo y usar el mismo método.

Comment: el "@" no funcionará si no ha comentado en esta publicacion o si no ha editado (y sido aceptado el edit). Para más informacion mira [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/15855)

Comment: Los `[^\s]` podrías reemplazarlos por `\S`, e incluso usar un cuantificador como en `(?:\s+\S+){3}` para facilitar la lectura... Además, es innecesario el `.*$` del final... Y no entiendo por qué estás dando un ejemplo con Notepad++ cuando la pregunta es de Python.... Pero sobre todo, no tiene sentido usar una expresión regular para algo que se soluciona con `split()`.

Comment: @Mariano La pregunta original no especificaba lenguaje. Yo estaba buscando etiquetas de Java y apareció esta pregunta. La recomendación de Notepad++ es para probar si la expresión que estás creando funciona sin tener que compilar y probar un programa.

Comment: El `.*$` puede ser útil cuando se trate de reemplazar la línea entera en NPP, de manera que el resultado final quede como: `^$1$` o `12.11.18.67`

Comment: Cuando no se especifica un lenguaje, es recomendable esperar a que el autor de la pregunta lo diga... Por otro lado, si bien no influye en un regex sencillo, Notepad++ no tiene el mismo motor de expresiones regulares que Python... Por ejemplo, `$` coincide con el final de la línea sin especificar un modificador sólo en Notepad++. Además, no se está buscando reemplazar, sino extraer una parte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte me ha servido para poder tener más claro regex.