# ¿Cómo saber si una línea de texto contiene una palabra con una expresión regular?

Tags: java, regex

Estoy recibiendo líneas de log y quiero saber cuáles contienen un término y cuáles contienen otro termino, para poder enviar las líneas de log a una ubicación u otra.

Estoy utilizando Apache Nifi, y hace uso de regular expressions para poder generar atributos que luego me permitirian derivar los logs a sus distintas ubicaciones.

Como entrada tengo esto por ejemplo:

```
1467, monday, texas, allow, smtp, mail,etc

1468, monday, texas, deny, smtp, mail,etc
```

¿Alguien sabe como con regex (java), es posible saber si contiene el termino 'allow' o si contiene el termino 'deny'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás buscando *una palabra*, y para eso podemos utilizar `\b`, un límite de palabra completa, que coincide con una posición entre un caracter de palabra (`\w` o `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) y un caracter que no es de palabra.

En definitiva, la siguiente expresión coincide con un string con la palabra `"allow"`.

```
\ballow\b
```

O en su representación como string:

```
regex = "\\ballow\\b";
```

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "\\ballow\\b";
final String texto = "1467, monday, texas, allow, smtp, mail,etc";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Contiene la palabra 'allow'");
}
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/LDFZ22520

---

Otra alternativa, más específica a un log, es buscar que la palabra esté

- al inicio del texto o después de una coma y un espacio: `(?:^|, )`
- y al final del texto o seguida por una coma y un espacio: `(?:$|, )`

```java
regex = "(?:^|, )allow(?:, |$)";
```

O sino, que esa palabra esté en el cuarto parámetro separado por comas:

```java
regex = "^(?:[^,]*,){3} allow(?:, |$)";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Mariano. Es perfecto!

Comment: Recién leo bien tu pregunta y veo que es una línea de un log... ¿No te conviene usar `split()` y obtener el cuarto parámetro? Aplica lo mismo que te respondieron en https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108815/127

Comment: Hola Mariano, lo del split fue perfecto para esa fase. Pero para realizar la distribucion de logs con apache nifi el tema cambia y he de usar normalmente expresiones regex, con lo que haz posteado en esta pregunta resulta muy efectivo. Gracias de nuevo.