# ¿Cómo filtrar renglones basado en una cadena especifica más texto adicional?

Tags: r, regex, string

Tengo una columna con texto parecido a lo siguiente:

```
cadenas <- c("el metro", "dos metrobuses", "pasó en el metro norte", "metro 12", "no")
```

Me interesa sólo obtener los elementos que estrictamente tienen la palabra "metro", es decir, los elementos 1, 3 y 4.

```
grepl("metro", cadenas)
```

Da TRUE para los primeros 4 y FALSE para el último. He intentado muchas combinaciones para obtener sólo los que me interesan sin ningún éxito.

```
cadenas[grepl("metro [[:alnum:]]", cadenas)] #Regresa los elementos 3 y 4 (resultado más cercano al deseado)
cadenas[grepl("\\ metro [[:alnum:]]", cadenas)] #Regresa el elemento 3
cadenas[grepl("\\ metro", cadenas)] #Regresa los elementos 1,2 y 3
```

He leído en muchos lados sin encontrar una respuesta que satisfaga mis requerimientos así que cualquier orientación la agradeceré enormemente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el patrón `\\b` ([word boundary / límite de palabras](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) para detectar `metro` como palabra completa:

```
cadenas <- c("el metro", "dos metrobuses", "pasó en el metro norte", "metro 12", "no")
cadenas[grepl("\\bmetro\\b", cadenas)]

[1] "el metro"               "pasó en el metro norte"
[3] "metro 12"
```

Comment: Buena respuesta @Patricio Moracho probé colocar el patrón `\\b` que indicaste sólo al final de `"metro\\b"` tomando esta referencia [Regular Expression in R](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html) y también funciona: `cadenas[grep("metro\\b", cadenas)]` dejo el test en [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LoathsomeDentalMacroinstruction)

Comment: @HubertRonald, si es cierto, la idea de usar `\\bmetro\\b` es para evitar palabras tipo `parametro`.

Comment: gracias por la acotación ya había votado a favor, sólo una consulta cuando se menciona palabras con parámetro, si entiendo bien es: [si una palabra contiene una expresión regular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109300/c%C3%B3mo-saber-si-una-l%C3%ADnea-de-texto-contiene-una-palabra-con-una-expresi%C3%B3n-regular)

Comment: Adicionalmente en este caso particular, por ejemplo salto de línea `\n` cuando se tiene `\nmetro`, `\nmetro\n` o `metro\n` al emplear el patrón `\\b` -a ambos lados o sólo al final- igual se imprime el salto de línea como carácter y realmente no sé a qué deba o si deba formularse como nueva pregunta. **Nota:** lo anterior puede verificarse acá [replit](https://repl.it/repls/LoathsomeDentalMacroinstruction)

Comment: @HubertRonald, el tema es que se trata de un patrón de búsqueda, no de reemplazo. `metro\n` coincide con el patrón `metro\\b` o `\\bmetro\\b`.

Comment: Perfecto @PatricioMoracho ya me quedó claro, se tendría que formular otra pregunta, para incluir el reemplazo y demás variantes a la pregunta original.

Comment: Busqué muchísimas referencias y en ninguna me topé con tu respuesta. Sin duda, gran parte de mi aprendizaje reciente en R te lo debo a ti. ¡Gracias!